# jquery count select dropdown which are not disabled and have specific option selected

Tags: jquery, count, dropdown

Using jquery how would I count  the number of all select dropdowns on the page which are not disabled and have a specific value selected, for ex. value="0"?

Comment: you have any code to show?

Comment: no really, couldn't find anything workable. I can count all selects on the page, and all disabled selects on the page, but not those that are not disabled and have specific option selected

Comment: you have jquery installed??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use this simple code

```
$('body select:not(:disabled) option[value="0"]:selected').length;
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/wrt7a2z9/1/)

> Note: be sure jquery included

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var count=0;
$("body select  option[value='0']:selected".each(
    function(index){  
        var selectElement = $(this);
         if(!selectElement.is(':disabled'))             
            count++;

    }
);
alert("count select:"count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach could be:

```js
$("select:enabled option:selected").filter(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('value') == 0) {
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: You can return  directly  `$(this).attr('value') == 0`